# Using a kotlin clause with enums instead of multiple if

Tags: if-statement, kotlin, enums

I am working with the next code:

```
  override fun presentNativeItem(dcsItem: DCSItem?): Any {
        if (dcsItem?.type == "NavMenu") {
            return buildNavMenu(dcsItem)
        } else if (dcsItem?.type == "NavLink") {
            return buildNavLink(dcsItem)
        } else if (dcsItem?.type == "Image") {
            return buildImage(dcsItem)
        }
        else throw IllegalStateException("Unknown Type ${dcsItem?.type} of NavItem")
    }
```

But instead of using multiple if, I would like to use the next enum:

```
enum class DSCType {
    NAVMENU,
    NAVLINK,
    IMAGE;

    override fun toString(): String {
        return this.name.toLowerCase()
    }

    companion object {
        fun fromString(value: String?): DSCType? {
            return when (value?.toLowerCase()) {
                "NavMenu" -> NAVMENU
                "NavLink" -> NAVLINK
                "Image" -> IMAGE
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how can I achieve that in the kotlin way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make your input parameter not nullable and change your function to:

```
override fun presentNativeItem(dcsItem: DCSItem) = when(dcsItem) {
    NAVMENU -> buildNavMenu(dcsItem)
    NAVLINK -> buildNavLink(dcsItem)
    IMAGE -> buildImage(dcsItem)
}
```

Comment: I am getting the next message: if over enum entry is not allowed use comparision instead.

Comment: You need to remove `is`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
fun presentNativeItem(dcsItem: DCSItem?): Any {
    return enumValues<DSCType>().firstOrNull { dcsItem?.type == it.typeName }
            ?.build(dcsItem)
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Unknown Type ${dcsItem?.type} of NavItem")
}

enum class DSCType(val typeName: String) {

    NAV_MENU("NavMenu") {
        override fun build(dcsItem: DCSItem?): Any {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
    },

    NAV_LINK("NavLink") {
        override fun build(dcsItem: DCSItem?): Any {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
    },

    IMAGE("Image") {
        override fun build(dcsItem: DCSItem?): Any {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
    };

    abstract fun build(dcsItem: DCSItem?): Any
}
```